# How to do Http Video Streaming PHP or an referece site to do this?

Tags: php, http, video, streaming

In one of my project i have a requirement for live or on demand video streaming. I am using PHP and AJAX for this project so i want to know how to do Http Video Streaming PHP or an referece site to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, so it might be hard to get you exactly what you want...

Still, here are a couple of questions/answers you might want to take a look at ; they might provide you with useful informations :

- [Live Video Streaming with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223983/live-video-streaming-with-php)
- [How to embed YouTube videos in PHP ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412467/how-to-embed-youtube-videos-in-php)
- [Streaming video file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847018/streaming-video-file)
- [Add dynamic video content (YouTube like) (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282683/add-dynamic-video-content-youtube-like-php)
- [How to display youtube-like video player in website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454791/how-to-display-youtube-like-video-player-in-website)
- Maybe also [Making a video sharing site, need a videoplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146468/making-a-video-sharing-site-need-a-videoplayer)

Hope those help ;-)

Have fun !

And if you have a more precise problem/question, don't hesitate to ask another question !